# Accuracy of Digit Recognition with Template Matching

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, c++

I have designed a C++ program to recognize the digits on an ID card based on OpenCV. First I preprocess the ID card image and then segment it based on contours. The segmentation results are as expected. Then I use the matchTemplate function with templates stored in the template path. However the recognition is inaccurate, for example $0$ may be recognized as $8$. Here is my template matching algorithm, matching the digit image with template images $j = 0$ to $j = 9$:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    string templatePath = "C:\\Users\\86188\\Desktop\\numbers\\" + to_string(j) + ".png";
    Mat templateImg = imread(templatePath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    resize(templateImg, templateImg, Size(digitWidth, height));
    Mat result;
    matchTemplate(digitImg, templateImg, result, TM_CCORR_NORMED);
    double matchVal;
    minMaxLoc(result, nullptr, &matchVal, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (matchVal > maxMatchVal) {
        maxMatchVal = matchVal;
        maxMatchNum = to_string(j);
    }
}
matchedNumbers.push_back(maxMatchNum);
```

Why is it inaccurate? Is there an accurate algorithm for digit recognition? According to [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html):

> Template Matching is a method for searching and finding the location
> of a template image in a larger image. OpenCV comes with a function
> cv.matchTemplate() for this purpose. It simply slides the template
> image over the input image (as in 2D convolution) and compares the
> template and patch of input image under the template image. Several
> comparison methods are implemented in OpenCV. (You can check docs for
> more details). It returns a grayscale image, where each pixel denotes
> how much does the neighbourhood of that pixel match with template.
>
> If input image is of size (WxH) and template image is of size (wxh),
> output image will have a size of (W-w+1, H-h+1). Once you got the
> result, you can use cv.minMaxLoc() function to find where is the
> maximum/minimum value. Take it as the top-left corner of rectangle and
> take (w,h) as width and height of the rectangle. That rectangle is
> your region of template.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I've requested an edit to the question according to the [rules](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Please review the edit request, thank you.

Comment: Ok，thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Don't use template matching; use a classifier to classify each digit.

Comment: Thanks,i will consider it